# Deploy Umbraco 500.19 error This configuration section cannot be used at this path

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, asp.net

0 down vote favorite

I have been running all over the web trying to find a solution to this problem. I am trying to deploy an umbraco site to a vps build is:

Windows Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5 Umbraco CMS

app pool integrated v4.0

I have tried many different solutions. II tried to do what was listed here: IIS - this configuration section cannot be used at this path (configuration locking?)

I found that I don't have 'in the features window, Click: "Internet Information Services"'. I'm not sure if that is related or not.
This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".

that is the error I am getting, error code 0x80070021. Its happening on this line . I have also tried the solution listed here:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1155232.aspx

to no avail. There shouldn't be any issues with file permissions either... I added IIS_IUSRS and IUSR with full control to see if that had any part.

Any info is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake... but have to admit the error wasn't very descriptive.

found the answer here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1735022.aspx

"Verify framework 2.0 is registered with IIS, If it is not registered, to do this

open the command promt=> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727 aspnet_regiis -i"

though I installed v4